How to pass credentials from kafka and database to FlinkSessionJob
I deployed a flink operator version 1.10 in k8s, the flink itself (FlinkDeployment) is deployed as a cluster session, I want to deploy several different FlinkSessionJobs and for each I need to define my own credentials for connecting to the Kafka topic and database, how do I pass them to the flink job?
My Kafka is deployed as a separate cluster, as is the database.
At first I thought to create a secret in k8s and pass values ​​from it in the
At first I thought to create a secret in k8s and pass the values ​​from it in the FlinkSessionJob manifest
For example, like this:
env:

name: KAFKA_USERNAME
valueFrom:
secretKeyRef:
name: kafka-secrets # Secret name in Kubernetes
key: username # Key inside the secret
name: KAFKA_PASSWORD
valueFrom:
secretKeyRef:
name: kafka-secrets # Secret name in Kubernetes
key: password # Key inside the secret

But as I understand it, the FlinkSessionJob manifest does not support the env parameter and, accordingly, it cannot be passed credentials in this way.
Here is my FlinkDeployment manifest:
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: basic-cluster
spec:
  image: flink:1.19
  flinkVersion: v1_19
  flinkConfiguration:
    taskmanager.numberOfTaskSlots: "24"
  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 0.5
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
          runAsNonRoot: true
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 0.5
    podTemplate:
      spec:
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 1000
          runAsNonRoot: true
  ingress:
    template: "flink-test-pull.ru/{{name}}(/|$)(.*)"
    className: "nginx"
    annotations:
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$2"
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required - flink'

Here is my FlinkSessionJob example:
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkSessionJob
metadata:
  name: flink-job-example
spec:
  deploymentName: basic-cluster
  job:
    jarURI: https://URL_to_my_app-0.0.1.jar
    parallelism: 2
    upgradeMode: stateless

I described everything in the description


FlinkSessionJob manifest does not support the env parameter

It does, via podTemplate.spec.env

with podTemplate.spec.env this also doesn't work.
error validating data: ValidationError(FlinkSessionJob.spec): unknown field "podTemplate" in org.apache.flink.v1beta1.FlinkSessionJob.spec

Your question already shows podTemplate being used in the Flink Deployment, not the SessionJob

it turns out that in order to transfer credentials via ENV, you will have to deploy FlinkDeployment for each task each time.
